# Permission denied error on IE8 and 7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Webpage error details

```
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; BRI/2)
Timestamp: Fri, 1 Jul 2011 01:21:21 UTC


Message: Permission denied
Line: 55
Char: 17
Code: 0
URI: http://www.testing.com/phone_select/


Message: Permission denied
Line: 55
Char: 17
Code: 0
URI: http://www.testing.com/phone_select/
```

Current domain is http://www.gale.testing.com/. This error occur when I tried to redirect to http://www.testing.com/phone_select/ with `top.window.location`

Is this because cross domain problem? But no ajax is involved. In Firefox and Chrome it works fine. IE7 and IE8 cause problems.

Comment: Did you check your IE browser security settings?, try to set the browser security setting to lowest and see if it works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use top.location.href instead?

Answer (score 0):

this problem is cause by IE 8 and 7 if using top.redirect. in an iframe, will trigger cross domain error. i solve it by create a redirect function at parent, and then call the function in iframe....